Format for SharePoint site location address to paste into R 'Go To Folder`
I am trying to open a Sharepoint site in the below format using the R 'Go To Folder' window:
https://[org name].sharepoint.com/sites/

I am getting the following error message:

\[org name].sharepoint.com@SSL\DAVWWWRoot is not accessible. You
might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the
administrator to find out if you have access permissions.
Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first
add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site,
and select the option to login automatically.


Tried various solutions, including hotfixes, registry fixes, etc.

Analyzed and concluded this problem is happening only on certain machines. Its not related to user permission on the client machine or on the SharePoint sites.
Tried KBs: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/912152, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2629108, with no luck
Tried adding site to Trusted sites zone and lowered security settings.
Tried running process monitor from client side and found WebDav access resulted in "Access Denied"
Perform Windows update on client machine.

Maybe it will help you, Good luck.
